# Что выбрать Visual Studio Team Services или GitHub?

Tags: visual-studio, github

Никогда не использовал ни GitHub ни Visual Studio Team Services, которые интегрированы в Visual Studio, но так сложилось, что надо сделать выбор.

Что выбрать? Какие плюсы и минусы есть у GitHub и Visual Studio Team Services? Проект небольшой и работают над ним 2-3 участника.

Краткое описание проекта приводится в соседнем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493488/).

Answer (score 2):

С начала решите: хотите вы использовать именно Git? Например, Hg получше с памятью обращается в окнах. Будете ли вы пользоваться веточками™? Может и svn сойдёт?

Затем, решите, публичный у вас проект или нет.
— Непубличные в гитхабе платные в bitbucket бесплатные для маленьких команд. 
— Публичные лучше всего хранить на Гитхабе, очевидно, более попсового вы не найдёте.

Затем решите, готовы вы потратить немного времени на настройку Git или хотите почти из коробки пользоваться контекстными меню и подсказками, что даёт Студия?

Если хотите, публичку и готовы потратить время на обговаривание как будете работать на публику — гитхаб.

Если хотите вроде бы приватные интегрированные с вашей IDE ништяки со всяким там автоматическим тестированием и (на любителя) системой issue — Visual Studio Team Services (до 5 бесплатно).

Если хотите того же самого, что на гитхабе, но в закрытом репозитории и маленькой командой — bitbucket.

sourceforge уж не буду форсить.

Comment: А при автомататическом тестировании в VSTS, компиляция выполняется на сервере Microsoft? Наверное есть какое-то ограничение на время компиляции или количество компиляций?

Comment: *потратить немного времени на настройку Git или хотите почти из коробки пользоваться контекстными меню и подсказками, что даёт Студия?* -- Студия сейчас прекрасно работает с гитом из коробки, с контекстными меню и подсказками. Для gitflow хватает. Правда в случае каких-то проблем приходится лезить в консоль, конечно же.

Comment: @AndrewCh вот, кроме шуток, вам лучше это всё узнать на хабрахабре или документации.

https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/pricing/calculator/?service=visual-studio-online — там посчитать можно (службы для разработчиков)

Comment: @andreycha ещё в 2012 году Студия отлично работала с Github и Git вообще (на любом хостинге, хоть своём). До тех пор, пока у тебя не появится, например, «две головы» по забывчивости=).

Comment: @higimo работать-то работало, но больно много багов и нестабильности было. В 2015-ой же все совсем хорошо.